# Is there any way to disable a pair of matched buttons based of the index of two array sets?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to build a game based on learning two foreign languages (Buttons matching game). There are two sets of buttons inside two different *tableLayoutPanels*. I've assigned the values of buttons using two array sets. The program will be executing like if a word is matched with its meaning in another language, then those two buttons will be disabled, after the clicks. The problem occurs when I'm setting up a condition for matching the buttons. I have matched them before by giving an if condition when the text values of the buttons were same. But now as the values (Text) of buttons are different, but the meaning of two different words are same, I want to match them by calling the array index of those array sets. How can I do that? Is there any better solution? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

I've tried matching the pair of buttons by setting up a if condition on firstButtonClick.Text == secondButtonClick.Text. But now I've to match the two different values of same meaning (two different language words).

```
    // two global array
    string[] words1 = new string[] {
    "Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4", "Book5",
    "Book6", "Book7", "Book8", "Book9", "Book10"
    };

    string[] words2 = new string[] {
    "Book1", "Book2", "Book3", "Book4", "Book5",
    "Book6", "Book7", "Book8", "Book9", "Book10"
    };

     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        assignValues1();
        assignValues2();
    }

    // function for assigning values inside the first set of buttons
    private void assignValues1()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        Array.Reverse(words1);

        foreach (Button btn in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < words1.Length; i++)
            {
                btn.Text = words1[counter]; 

            }
            counter++;
        }
    }

    // function for assigning values inside the second set of buttons
    private void assignValues2()
    {
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (Button btn in tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < words1.Length; i++)
            {
                btn.Text = words2[counter]; 
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }

    Button btnClicks1, btnClicks2;

    // this function below is applied in all the buttons in two different 
    // tableLayoutPanels

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedBtn = sender as Button;

        if (btnClicks1 != null && btnClicks2 != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (clickedBtn.BackColor == Color.Coral)
            return;

        if (btnClicks1 == null)
        {
            btnClicks1 = clickedBtn;
            btnClicks1.BackColor = Color.Coral;
            return;
        }

        btnClicks2 = clickedBtn;
        btnClicks2.BackColor = Color.Coral;

        // the problems happens here. which condition should I use. Or is
        // there any better solution then as I'm trying to do?

        for (int i = 0; i < words1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < words2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (words1[i] == words2[j])
                {
                    btnClicks1.Enabled = false;
                    btnClicks2.Enabled = false;

                    btnClicks1 = null;
                    btnClicks2 = null;
                }
                else
                    timer1.Start();
            }
        }
        /*
        // When the values inside the text of the buttons were same.

        if (btnClicks1.Text == btnClicks2.Text)
        {
            checkingArrayValue();
            btnClicks1 = null;
            btnClicks2 = null;
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }*/
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();

        btnClicks1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        btnClicks2.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

        btnClicks1 = null;
        btnClicks2 = null;
    }
```

I wanted to match the buttons of same meaning from two different languages and disable the two buttons but all I'm getting is an exception.

Comment: `all I'm getting is an exception`  Always helps if you tell us the exception.

Comment: The exception is said that as I'm setting the two button clicks to null, it is being unhandled. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
". If I comment them, the program runs with bug. It disabled two buttons after being clicked without caring about matching them.